# Get the IP of the website the client is using to request the data

Tags: php

I'm trying to only allow certain IPs to use a PHP resource, I've tried using the server referer, but I've sadly experienced that it can be easily spoofed, as its a client header and it can be easily modified.

I want the resource to be accessible from a website, but the IP from the client visiting the website is not the same IP from the one the website has.
**This means that the client shouldn't be able to access the resource directly via the browser or curl, but it should be allowed if done via a website.**

I guess I can use some of these $server keys:

```
'HTTP_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_FORWARDED','REMOTE_ADDR'
```

But **I have no idea which one to use in order to get the website IP** to see if it matches with the expected **and which one returns the IP of the client.**

What I've tried, but doesnt work because it can be spoofed

```
public function getHost()
{
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if ($url != null) {
        return gethostbyname($url["host"]); // returns referer IP's
    }
}
```

its clear the getHost() should return a key from the mentioned above, but I'm not sure which one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the request is made by the browser, i.e. the client itself, then you can not restrict by IPs, period. The request would need to come from that 3rd party’s web server, so client makes request to 3rd party server which makes a request to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to test if @deceze was right, so I did some testing
[image: left: local, right: same host]

Left: local, Right: same host
[image: left: local, right: cross-site]

left: local, right: cross-site

---

So, sadly, he is, there is no way to check that using $_server, and referer its not reliable, solution, perform js requests from your server directly and inject them as content, showing pre-rendered data